# Writing a query to add key from multiple values

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, redis

I am parsing a DBF file, which is like

```
"{\"srCode\":\"EUCRDCTN\",\"accountCode\":\"\",\"priceList\":\"EUCN\",\"discount\":null,\"termDays\":30}"
"{\"srCode\":\"\",\"accountCode\":\"MEN006\",\"priceList\":\"EUSD\",\"discount\":10,\"termDays\":null}"
```

in some places i have a value in srCode and in other i have it in accountCode

what is the correct way to insert this into one redis set, so that, i get something like:

i did this on the redis-cli

```
☺  redis-cli                                                                                                                                                               2.1.0""
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET test "MEN006" "{\"srCode\":\"\",\"accountCode\":\"MEN006\",\"priceList\":\"EUSD\",\"discount\":10,\"termDays\":null}"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET test "GBCRDCTN" "{\"srCode\":\"EUCRDCTN\",\"accountCode\":\"\",\"priceList\":\"EUCN\",\"discount\":null,\"termDays\":30}"
OK

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall "test"
1) "GBCRDCTN"
2) "{\"srCode\":\"EUCRDCTN\",\"accountCode\":\"\",\"priceList\":\"EUCN\",\"discount\":null,\"termDays\":30}"
3) "MEN006"
4) "{\"srCode\":\"\",\"accountCode\":\"MEN006\",\"priceList\":\"EUSD\",\"discount\":10,\"termDays\":null}"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

this works, but in my code, which is coffeescript, i have

```
exports.router = () ->
  express.Router()
    .post "/buyers", buyers
    .use (req,res) -> res.status(404).send("Invalid API Call")

buyers = (req, res, next) ->
  console.log req.body
  buyersMap = _(req.body).map( (r) -> [r.accountCode, JSON.stringify(r)] ).zipObject().value()
  srCodeMap = _(req.body).map( (r) -> [r.srCode, JSON.stringify(r)] ).zipObject().value()
  hmsetPr "buyers", buyersMap
  hmsetPr "buyers", srCodeMap
    .then (result) -> res.status(200).send("Ok")
    .catch next
```

so if i search for

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hget "buyers" "EUCRDSTD"
(nil)
```

but if i change the code to `hmsetPr "terms", srCodeMap`  i get a result

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hget "terms" "EUCRDSTD"
"{\"srCode\":\"EUCRDSTD\",\"accountCode\":\"\",\"priceList\":\"EUSD\",\"discount\":null,\"termDays\":30}"
```

what am i missing?

any advise much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

ok, my code should be:

```
buyers = (req, res, next) ->
  buyersMap = _(req.body).map((r) ->
    if r?.srCode then [r.srCode, JSON.stringify(r)]
    [r.accountCode, JSON.stringify(r)]
  ).zipObject().value()
  hmsetPr("buyers", buyersMap).then((result) ->
    res.status(200).send "Ok"
  )["catch"] next
```